# How I can draw the graph of three equations (x=x(u,v,w), y=y(u,v,w), z=z(u,v,w)) involving three parameters using Matlab?

Tags: matlab-figure

I have got three equations involving three parameters 
`x=u*cos(2*pi*v)`, `y=u*sin(2*pi*v)`, `z=sqrt(1-u^2)*(2*w-1)`,
where `u`, `v`, `w` belong to `[0,1]`.

How can I draw the graph of above equations using matlab?
I have tried three nested for loops, but it's really time taking. The graph obtained in this way consists of dots and its quality is not so good.

Is there any other way to draw the graph of these equations in Matlab?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of what you've tried and then explain how it is not in accordance to the desired results

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop to create the matrix for the calculations. Below is an example for creating the matrices and also plotting. It might not be exactly what you are looking for, but it should get you close.

```
% set up values to calc for for u,v,w in [0,1]
stepsize = 0.1;
u = 0:stepsize:1; % min, step, max
v = 0:stepsize:1;
w = 0:stepsize:1;

% now set up combined tables
u = u';
v = v';
w = w';

uv = [repmat(u, length(v),1), repmat(v, length(u),1)];
uw = [repmat(u, length(w),1), repmat(w, length(u),1)];


% now do calcs
% note u-vector is uv(:,1) or uw(:,1), depending upon the combo, etc.
x = uv(:,1) .* cos(2 * pi * uv(:,2));
y = uv(:,1) .* sin(2 * pi * uv(:,2));
z = sqrt(1 - uw(:,1) .^2) .* (2 * uw(:,2) -1);

% it's not clear what you want to plot, but here are some examples
figure
hold on
subplot(4,1,1)
plot(x, y, 'Color', 'green', 'DisplayName', 'XY');
box on
title('Your Title Here', 'FontSize', 10)
xlabel('X', 'FontSize', 8)
ylabel('Y', 'FontSize', 8)
set(legend, 'Location', 'best')

subplot(4,1,2)
plot(x, z, 'Color', 'blue', 'DisplayName', 'XZ');
box on
title('Your Title Here', 'FontSize', 10)
xlabel('X', 'FontSize', 8)
ylabel('Z', 'FontSize', 8)
set(legend, 'Location', 'best')

subplot(4,1,3)
plot(y, z, 'Color', 'red', 'DisplayName', 'YZ');
box on
title('Your Title Here', 'FontSize', 10)
xlabel('Y', 'FontSize', 8)
ylabel('Z', 'FontSize', 8)
set(legend, 'Location', 'best')

subplot(4,1,4)
plot3(x, y, z, 'Color', 'magenta', 'DisplayName', 'XYZ');
box on
grid on
ax = gca;
ax.GridAlpha = 0.5;
title('Your Title Here', 'FontSize', 10)
xlabel('X', 'FontSize', 8)
ylabel('Y', 'FontSize', 8)
zlabel('Y', 'FontSize', 8)
set(legend, 'Location', 'best')
```

The above produces this figure:
[image]